# JAXRS PUT-Request with Json from jquery --> 415

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jax-rs

I try to make a simple put-request with a jquery-ajax-call. I try to pass a normal json object but each time I get error 415.
The coding of the ajax call looks like the following:

```
$.ajax(
 type: "PUT",
 contentType: "application/json",
 url: myURL + "/UpdateUser/User/" + localStorage.getItem("user"),
 dataType: "json",
 data: model,
 success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
 },
 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
 }
});
```

The model is a simple javascript variable with is converted into json. 
The JAXRS coding looks like the following:

```
@Path("/UpdateUser")
public class UpdateUser{

     @PUT
     @Path("/User/{user}")
     @Consumes("application/json")
     @Produces("application/json")
     public String updateUser(@PathParam("user") String pUser, User pObject){
       String return_val = "runs";

        return(return_val);
     }
}
```

Everytime when I run this code I get - as I already mentioned - the error 415. First I thought that I could have forgotten the content type ... but ... that was not the problem...
I really hope that you can help me solving this problem!

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

As you did not provide enough information, I can only suppose what the problem is: Jersey is not configured to support JSON. That is described in details [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html). Besides more details to the problem you can probably find in the logs.